# AWS Postgresql RDS instance "does not exist" with docker-compose and Django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-rds

My RDS and web container are not connected.

But I did all the database-related settings in `Django`'s settings, and I also set up `AWS RDS` properly.

What should I do more?

This is `DATABASES` of settings file of `Django`.

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("SQL_DATABASE"),
        "USER": env("SQL_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("SQL_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("SQL_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("SQL_PORT"),
    }
}
```

I skipped the `docker-compose.yml` with `nginx-proxy` or `TLS`.

When I tested in local, I made and mounted DB containers on `docker-compose`, but in `prod` environments, I didn't make DB containers because I use `AWS RDS`.
Will this be a problem?

Please help me.

(ps.All of `PROJECT_NAME` replaced the actual project name.)

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
    image: project:web
    command: gunicorn PROJECT_NAME.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - envs/.env.prod
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - config/docker/entrypoint.prod.sh

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

This is what I've got error from `docker`

```
Waiting for postgres...
PostgreSQL started

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2" does not exist

[2021-09-18 15:09:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-09-18 15:09:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2021-09-18 15:09:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-09-18 15:09:21 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
```

Comment: When you connect to your RDS database cluster using for example a myself client, do you see that it contains a db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2 db?

Comment: Why does docker say"Waiting for postgres...
PostgreSQL started" if you are not setting up the database within docker?

Comment: edit the config file with the password so that it has the wrong password.  This should clarify if you are actually using the config file you think you are, and if so then the new error message might give some more clues.

Comment: @LRutten You mean, do you ask if there is db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2 in the DB id of AWS RDS? Then yes.

Comment: @jjanes The reason is because I call ENTRYPOINT like this 
`ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/config/docker/entrypoint.prod.sh"]`
entrypoint.prod.sh
`
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z "$SQL_HOST" "$SQL_PORT"; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi
`
And I didn't set the DB in the docker file.
Can't we set it up just in django settings?

Comment: @justzino No I actually meant if there is a database at all configured in your database cluster. The RDS is just a managed machine  on which you can create, modify and delete databases but you need to create the database INSIDE the cluster to be able to connect to it. I'm wondering if you did that step.

Comment: @LRutten I just followed the steps out [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-docker-https-aws/#aws-rds).
And I don't think I create the database.

Comment: There is a step: `Open Additional configuration and change Initial database name to djangoec2`. Did you follow this exactly? If so, this means there should be a database withe name djangoec2, not db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2.

Comment: @LRutten I followed it, but I changed DB Instance identifier to db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2

Comment: @justzino Ok and if you log into the the db yourself using a postgresql client, does everything seem ok? If so, you probably know it's related to the docker image, and not the DB. Also, I assume this is all deployed on an EC2 instance?

Comment: @LRutten Thank you so much for your answers. I solved the problem. When I created a new DB in RDS, it was solved. As you said, it seems that the DB creation setting was not properly set up while creating an instance in RDS. And the DB instance name was db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2, but the DB name had a separate setting.

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely the reason is that the `AWS RDS` **DB instance name** differs from PostgreSQL **DB name**.

As per [AWS RDS manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html)

> For **Databases**, choose the name of the new DB instance.
>
> On the RDS console, the details for the new DB instance appear. The DB instance has a status of **creating** until the DB instance is created and ready for use. When the state changes to **available**, you can connect to the DB instance. Depending on the DB instance class and storage allocated, it can take several minutes for the new instance to be available.

As per [PostgreSQL: Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html)

> *`dbname`*
>
> Specifies the name of the database to be created. The name must be unique among all PostgreSQL databases in this cluster. The default is to create a database with the same name as the current system user.

Default `dbname` is `postgres`

So, you may want to try `postgres` instead `db-PROJECT_NAME-ec2` as a DB name.

Comment: Although I've already solved the problem, thank you for your answer.

Default db user name is postgres, but default db name wasn't postgres when I create RDS Instance.

Comment: It's both. The default username is 'postgres' and the default database name is 'postgres' too, which isn't reflected in the database settings once the database is created (there is just a dash).